# Appinventor app behavior

Tags: app-inventor

I have made an app that calls my mobile website.  The mobile website has a click-to-call button, and when touching this button in my app, I get an error message saying "Webpage not available".  This is not a problem if I visit my site through the browser.  Anyone having an idea what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using the webviewer component? The webviewer is no full browser...
You could add a button in App Inventor and use the [phone call component](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/social.html#PhoneCall) alternatively.

or you could use the activity starter to start a full browser to display your page, more info see [here](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/using-activity-starter.html)

> **Open the browser to a Web page**
>
> Use these activity starter properties to open a specific web page:
>
> Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
>   DataUri: http://news.google.com

Comment: Thanks Talifun!  I now understand that calling a web-site through the App Inventor app does not necessarily mean that I will get all the functionality.  So, I'll better build the app from scratch.  We learn as long as we live! :)

Comment: in case your question is answered, please mark it as accepted, see also [how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)  `When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. `